# How to sign pieces of data (ie strings of text) with golang?

Tags: go-ethereum, signature, golang

I'm trying to figure out how to sign a piece of data (in this case a string) using golang. So far everything I can find is about signing transactions which wont work for signing pieces of data that is not of a type transaction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out:

```
// convert string key to byte array
byteKey := []byte(`{....}`)

privKey, err := keystore.DecryptKey(byteKey, string(pass))
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal("error decrypting key")
} else {
    fmt.Printf("key successfully decrypted %v\n", privKey)
}

hash := crypto.Keccak256([]byte("hello"))

sig, err := crypto.Sign(hash, privKey.PrivateKey)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal("error signing data")
} else {
    fmt.Println("signature successful ", sig)
}
```

Comment: and how do you verify the signature? is the snippet code also simple?

Comment: In golang or solidity?

Comment: in golang ... ...

Comment: Ah okay, i'm verifying the signatures in smart contracts using solidity, but with golang it's even simpler, literally one command: https://godoc.org/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/crypto#VerifySignature